# How to I configure exim4 to allow pound sign (hash) to be part of the email address?

Tags: exim

It seems that exim4 refuses to receive emails send to "#xxx@example.com" and these are quite common in Exchange environments.

How can I comfigure exim4 to allow the hash symbol in email addresses.

Clarifications: Yes, I am aware that # sign is not allowed by the RFC, but I am stuck with a setup where I have to use exim4 filtering capabilities for removing certain messages generated by some servers, before these are delivered to corporate Exchange servers.

Comment: `#xxx@example.com" and these are quite common in Exchange environments`  They are?  That... doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: I'm kind of hoping I'm wrong, and someone can find you a different answer, but at least [as of 2004, this was not possible in Exim](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/exim/users/29610#29610).  I can't find any indication that it's been corrected since then, either, despite the claim that the bug would be fixed in due course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment this seems not to be possible so I raise a bug:
http://bugs.exim.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1465

Still, there is an workaround

if you have split config, edit `30_exim4-config_check_rcpt` and comment the lines below:

```
#  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS
#  deny
#    domains = !+local_domains
#    local_parts = CHECK_RCPT_REMOTE_LOCALPARTS
#    message = restricted characters in address
#  .endif
```

If you have any interest on getting this fixed, please add your vote/comment to this bug.

Answer (score 1):

The # within email address is not compliant to RFC822 (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6.1).
So exim is doing a good job with rejecting this address.

Comment: I added more details regarding why I do need this, I am fully aware that this is not allowed by RFC, but also I have no option.

Comment: We're really sorry that MS has decided (yet again) that it doesn't need to obey the rules of the internet.  But their decision to do so doesn't change the standard, nor magically enable all other compliant software to support their arbitrary decisions.  **What you want to do can't be done.**  You might get luckier with a different MTA, but that's something you'll need to look into for yourself.

Comment: To me it seems that RFC 5322 Section 3.2.3 allows #

Answer (score 1):

The hash (#) is perfectly legal in the local part of an email address. RFC 5321 refers to RFC5322 for the definition of an atom:

> 3.2.3.  Atom atext           =   ALPHA / DIGIT /    ; Printable US-ASCII
>                          "!" / "#" /        ;  characters not including
>                          "$" / "%" /        ;  specials.  Used for atoms.
>                          "&" / "'" /
>                          "*" / "+" /
>                          "-" / "/" /
>                          "=" / "?" /
>                          "^" / "_" /
>                          "`" / "{" /
>                          "|" / "}" /
>                          "~"

All these characters are legal on the left hand side of an email address. Exim's default configuration prevents use of some of these characters, because they're unsafe if Exim is going to save the message to a mailbox named for the local-part of the address. However, it does not prevent the use of the hash character.

The default config uses these ACLs:

> deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
>             domains       = +local_domains
>             local_parts   = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]
>
>   deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
>             domains       = !+local_domains
>             local_parts   = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\.\./

This isn't an Exim bug, but it may be a bug in the default configuration of some third party distribution.